# Cordova Build - Could not find an installed version of Gradle

Tags: cordova, gradle

I am trying to build a Cordova project. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. I run `sudo cordova build android` but the build fails with this message:

`Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio`

It seems strange to me that when I run `cordova requirements android`, I get this:

`Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25
Gradle: installed /home/viktor/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/4.0.2/bin/gradle`

It looks like Gradle is installed.

Path to Gradle also appears in `$PATH`:

`echo $PATH`:

`/home/viktor/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/home/viktor/bin:/home/viktor/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/snap/bin`

Cordova version is 7.0.1.

Could someone please help me to figure out why the build fails even though Gradle is installed?

**Edit:**
Ok, I tried to create a brand new project by `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`. This project can be successfully built and run. What could be wrong with the project I'm trying to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Some of the files in the project were locked, owned by root. When I used just

`cordova build android`

an error message popped up saying that some file can't be read.

Therefore, when building, I used

`sudo cordova build android`.

That helped me to get rid of the permission problem but it also was the actual cause of the problem with Gradle...

...when a command is run with `sudo` the `$PATH` variable used is different (restricted). In my case, this is the value that was used when building without `sudo`:

`/home/viktor/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/home/viktor/bin:/home/viktor/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/viktor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/snap/bin`

And this is `$PATH` with `sudo`:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

As you may see, the latter is missing the path to Gradle.

So, the solution here was to `chmod` and `chown` the project files and build without `sudo` just using

`cordova build android`.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 & here is how I fixed it,

1) Open ~/.bashrc file.
2) Add these lines to the end.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:~/Android/Sdk/tools
export GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-studio/gradle
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME/gradle-4.6/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME/m2repository
```

Remember to replace these paths according to your setup (If you use flatpaks, snaps..etc). I don't know why m2repository is there. But without it, cordova build failed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

also for those using an old version of android studio, it might be the problem. I unistalled it and installed android studio 3 (in Oct 2017) and installed all build tools, updated the cordova module(npm update cordova) and everything now works like clockwork!! windows7 user!!

Comment: Oddly it worked fine for me on old version, but has not worked since I uninstalled the old versions and did fresh Android Studio and Tools installs.  The files it's looking for don't exist on my disk at all, it's as if they are no longer part of the Android tools.  :-(